# apt upgrade not working for mysql-client

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

apt is not upgrading `mysql-client`. Instead getting message:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-client
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libqt5concurrent5 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 libxml2
12 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,416 kB of archives.
After this operation, 98.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Not even uninstalling, when tried to remove it remove mysql-community-server as well.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove mysql-client
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client mysql-community-server
```

#### System, Apt and MySQL info

```
$ apt -v
apt 1.9.4 (amd64)

$ uname -a
Linux vinays-rog 5.3.0-7625-generic #27~1576774560~19.10~f432cd8-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 20:35:37 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Pop!_OS 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan

$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

$ apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
mysql-client/eoan-security,eoan-security,eoan-updates,eoan-updates 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10]
mysql-client/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3]
mysql-client/eoan,eoan 8.0.17-0ubuntu2 amd64

$ sudo apt list --installed -a '*mysql*'
Listing... Done
libmysqlclient21/eoan-security,eoan-updates,now 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmysqlclient21/eoan 8.0.17-0ubuntu2 amd64

mysql-apt-config/now 0.8.14-1 all [installed,local]
mysql-apt-config/unknown,unknown 0.8.13-1 all

mysql-client/eoan-security,eoan-security,eoan-updates,eoan-updates 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10]
mysql-client/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3]
mysql-client/eoan,eoan 8.0.17-0ubuntu2 amd64

mysql-common/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,local]
mysql-common/eoan,eoan 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 amd64

mysql-community-client-core/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,local]

mysql-community-client/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,local]

mysql-community-server-core/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,local]

mysql-community-server/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,local]

mysql-connector-java/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 all [installed,local]

php-mysql/eoan,eoan,now 2:7.3+69ubuntu2 all [installed]

php7.3-mysql/eoan-security,eoan-updates,now 7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.2 amd64 [installed]
php7.3-mysql/eoan 7.3.8-1 amd64

$ apt policy mysql-client
mysql-client:
  Installed: 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10
  Candidate: 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3
  Version table:
     8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main i386 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.0.17-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages
```

I just wanted to remove `mysql-client`.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t, the `mysql-community-server` package depends on `mysql-client`:

```
Package: mysql-community-server
Source: mysql-community
Version: 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
Installed-Size: 167
Pre-Depends: debconf (>= 0.2.17), adduser
Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10), mysql-client (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10), mysql-community-server-core (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10), perl, psmisc, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
```

Comment: I was thinking that, purging and reinstalling will solve my problem. `apt` is not able to upgrade to latest version of `mysql-client`. I see three different version available for `mysql-client`.

```
mysql-client/eoan-security,eoan-security,eoan-updates,eoan-updates 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10]
mysql-client/now 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3]
mysql-client/eoan,eoan 8.0.17-0ubuntu2 amd64
```

Comment: OK, so your question is really about upgrading `mysql-client`, correct? Could you [edit it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/566937/edit) to show the output of `apt policy mysql-client`, and `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: updated in question

Comment: That’s not quite what I asked for.

Comment: I updated **Question** with output of both command `apt policy mysql-client`, and `sudo apt upgrade`. Please see **Question** in starting for upgrade command output